# Rails docker-compose mismatch but is same version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am building a Rails/Spree eCommerce app, and using the test repo, which sets up with docker compose (bin/setup) and Postgres, I get error that is wrong version of docker-compose but in fact I have the same version installed see bash output below.

```
anton@anton-ThinkCentre-E73:~/Projects/Rails/ecom-rails$ bin/setup
ERROR: Version "1.29.2" in "./docker-compose.yml" is invalid.
anton@anton-ThinkCentre-E73:~/Projects/Rails/ecom-rails$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

Any idea why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 2 concepts here:

- docker-compose version:

This means the version of `docker-compose` script itself, e.g. `1.29.2` you have.

- Compose file format version:

This means the file format version defined in `docker-compose.yaml`, e.g `3.8`, so for you, you need to use `file format version` something like `version: "3"`.

Details refers [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Comment: Yes, I set it to 3.8 for the latest release, worked. Thanks